# Ruby Savon: Call SOAP webservice without operation

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I need to call a SOAP service that doesn’t contain any operation encapsulation on the body.

Normally with Savon (Ruby 2.3, Savon 2.11) we have:

```
client = Savon.client(endpoint: 'http://example.com', namespace: 'http://v1.example.com')
response = client.call(:opName, message_hash)
```

And this will generate a request like:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://v1.example.com" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
       <wsdl:opName>
           ...message content ...
       </wsdl:opName>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But I dont want it to generate the `<wsdl:opName>` node. I tried to pass`nil` as the operation but it generates the tag as `<wsdl:>`.

I want to generate a SOAP request without it, like:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://v1.example.com" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
       ...message content ...
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried to build the XML yourself and just pass it to the call?

Comment: Yes that's an option. I just want to know if there is a workaround on Savon API.